# Errors installing ROS Kinetic from source on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, build-from-source, opencv3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been trying hard to install ROS Kinetic from source (so I can change some feature in it) on *clean*, freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 setup according to the [Installing from source](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source) manual (steps below) (Note, I was able install ROS Kinetic release on an other clean Ubuntu.)

```
sudo apt-get install python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool python-rosinstall build-essential
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update
mkdir ~/ros_catkin_ws
cd ~/ros_catkin_ws
rosinstall_generator desktop_full --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar > kinetic-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall
wstool init -j8 src kinetic-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall
```

At this point I get stuck in an infinite loop of

```
[opencv3] still active
[opencv3] still active
[opencv3] still active
[opencv3] still active
```

After killing it, and continuing with the following step:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y
```

I get stuck in the unrecoverable error

```
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-opencv3
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-kinetic-opencv3] failed
```

I have no idea how to continue from here. Could somebody please help?

---

Edit: OK, now to get past the error one needs to get rid of the `-j8` flag. Some kind of race condition in the package management. It would be **great** if the documentation would be properly updated.

Note however I get a new error:

```
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y shiboken2] failed
```

This is a mess...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276740/errors-installing-ros-kinetic-from-source-on-ubuntu-16.04/) by [shardator](https://answers.ros.org/users/32772/shardator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-11-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-27**:\

> I've been trying hard to install ROS Kinetic from source (so I can change some feature in it)

Not an answer, but if you just want to "change some feature", you don't need to install *everything* from source. This depends a bit on what it is exactly that you want to work on (`roscpp` fi will ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-27**:
.. increase the set of pkgs that you'd need to built from sources significantly), but any package that you add to a Catkin workspace will automatically be found "first", shadowing the system-installed version (ie: from `.deb`s).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-27**:\

> It would be great if the documentation would be properly updated.

What would you like to see added? (anecdotal, but) I use this command almost daily and it's pretty robust, even with higher nrs of concurrent downloads.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-27**:\

> ```
> [opencv3] still active
> ```
>
> After killing it, [..]
>
> ```
> E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-opencv3
> ```

This makes perfect sense: you don't have the ROS pkgs repositories configured/enabled, cancelled the download of `opencv3` (so it's not part of your workspace) and then ask `rosdep` ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-27**:
.. to install all *missing dependencies* using binary (ie: released) packages. `opencv3` is probably a dependency of some pkgs in `desktop-full`, so `rosdep` is going to try to install it.

No pkg repos -> trying to install `ros-kinetic-opencv3` -> error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just installed Kinetic from sources on a clean/fresh/pristine `ubuntu:xenial` Docker image using the steps you list in your question text.

The missing `shiboken2` is essentially [ros-infrastructure/rosdep#465](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/465).

Reason is that you probably haven't added the ROS package repositories to your system (`shiboken2` is an imported pkg, not hosted by the regular Ubuntu repositories). This is not too clear right now I grant you that, but section `1.1` (*Installing bootstrap dependencies*) of the *Prerequisites* section of the tutorial you link does say this:

> If you have trouble installing the packages in the command above, make sure you have added the packages.ros.org debian repository to your apt source lists as described starting here: [kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2BAC8-Ubuntu.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2BAC8-Ubuntu.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list)

If you do that (add the repository *and* import the key), `shiboken2` should be found and `rosdep` should be able to install all dependencies.

---

Edit:

> This is a mess...

I feel that is a bit of an exaggeration: a source install is essentially almost a copy-paste affair with on the order of 10 commands. For a system as complex as ROS that would seem to be completely manageable and there is a lot of work that is automated to the point where you're basically just sitting there, waiting.

> It would be great if the documentation would be properly updated.

Indeed. The wiki is just that, a wiki. If you feel that some things could be improved, please register for an account and improve the installation documentation. That would be great.

---

Edit2: there was one additional issue that I ran into, which I've reported at [ros/ros_comm#1248](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1248). This should not be necessary (as the PR already appears to include everything to maintain bw-compatibility), but I had to edit the `CMakeLists.txt` of `xmlrpcpp` to work-around the issue reported. See the PR for more info.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shardator](https://answers.ros.org/users/32772/shardator/) on 2017-11-27**:
I do not feel that I could properly update the Wiki. I'm new to ROS, and in a deep dive (I'm working on a not-so-hobby project). Sorry if I sound upset.

What bothers me is that the operation of the install scripts is not deterministic, for example I could get over errors by rerunning scripts.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-27**:
No problem.

I would still recommend you make sure that you absolutely need to build everything from sources, vs just some particular packages. That would probably be a much less involved exercise.

**Comment by [shardator](https://answers.ros.org/users/32772/shardator/) on 2017-11-30**:
I'm very much afraid of trying to build some of the packages if it is so difficult to build all of them. :( Also, I after successfully building all, and building the robot code I have to work on, I get a runtime error, while if I install ROS binaries, I do not... So something is extremely weird here

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-01**:\

> I'm very much afraid of trying to build some of the packages if it is so difficult to build all of them

this confuses me a bit: building a subset has always been easier for me, as the subset typically needs a lot less dependencies to be present. Mixing binaries with from-source built should ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-01**:
.. work.

> So something is extremely weird here

it would seem that something strange is going on, but without more info I can't help you.